# Can I do carousel with components React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation, carousel

I want to achieve [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FqGybegK7YTfJJJ-tMMDDA8TNWwK4dB8/view?usp=sharing) feature. I have been trying to achieve this using react-native-snap-carousel.

I just want to know what is the approach to achieve this, is Carousel my best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wizard package.
Or you can search the term "multi step form" or "wizard step form" and you will find similar packages.